# Installing more files with `python setup.py develop`

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-2.x, setuptools, distutils

I'm working on Swift extensions to Python 2. Since distutils/setuptools only support C/C++ extensions, I'm on the hook to modify the build commands to make them build Swift code.

My runs of `python setup.py build` and `python setup.py install` appear successful: the package and its contents are in the correct location and the native extensions load properly on `import`.

However, my team prefers to use `pip install -e .`, which eventually does `python setup.py develop`, to accelerate development a little bit; and as it stands, `setup.py` does not know to copy the native libraries that `build` compiles to the source directories.

In my current setup:

- the `SwiftBuildExt` class (which extends Cython's, because we, uh, support language diversity)...
- ...overrides `run` to build Swift modules that are found dynamically with `glob`.
- `run` adds entries to a list that I'll call `swift_modules`;
- `get_output`, after `run` has executed, is overridden to return the base's files and `swift_modules`.

What do I need to change to get `develop` to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it reading the source for [`setuptools.command.develop`](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/blob/master/setuptools/command/develop.py#L110): `develop` runs the `build_ext` command with the `inplace` parameter, which tells `build_ext` to save the build output to the source tree. This parameter can predictably be tested with `self.inplace` from the `build_ext` subclass. From there, it's only a matter of changing where the files are copied.

It's handled in a different way in Python 3, which I have not explored.